# Trouble programmatically accessing image url in React app when hosting backend on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a simple chat and draw app using websockets in React with a Ruby on Rails backend. I deployed the backend API to Heroku, and since then I have had trouble getting the chat avatars to show up in the chat. Either it breaks my code, or only a broken image link appears.

My message component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Message = props => {
  let options = { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", weekday: 'long', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
  let sentOn = new Date(props.message.created_at).toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)
  let imgSrc = `../img/${props.message.user.avatar}.png`
  return (
    <div className="message">
      <img className="chat-avi" src={require(imgSrc)} alt={`${props.message.user.avatar}`}/>
      <h5 className="msg-user-name">{props.message.user.name} ({props.message.user.pronouns})</h5>
      <p className="message-content">{props.message.content}</p>
      <p className="sent-on">sent on: {sentOn}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Message;
```

I have also tried:

```
<img className="chat-avi" src={require(`../img/${props.message.user.avatar}.png`)} alt={`${props.message.user.avatar}`}/>
```

and

```
<img className="chat-avi" src={imgSrc} alt={`${props.message.user.avatar}`}/>
```

When I use require inside the src attribute my app breaks, and when I do not use require inside the src attribute I get a broken image link.

Elsewhere on the app, I am successfully seeing images rendered with, for example, this code:

```
<img className="avi-img" onClick={this.changeAvatar} src={require("../img/pink_fairy_armadillo.png")} alt="pink_fairy_armadillo"/>
```

As you can see, the main difference is that in the code where my src attribute is not working as expected, I need to get something from props and pass that in as part of the image URL. When I look at a successfully rendered image element in developer tools, I see something like this:

```
<img class="avi-img" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU+[and etc as a long string]" alt="pink_fairy_armadillo">
```

The src URL for the broken image elements are not being transformed into a similar thing. When my app breaks, I get a message like "Error: Cannot find module '../img/pink_fairy_armadillo.png'."

My app does work as expected when running locally, the problem only occurs on Heroku. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What kind of build tooling are you using?

Comment: @Jkarttunen thank you so much for responding.I'm on the free tier, but so far only the backend is deployed to Heroku. I am running the client on localhost with yarn start, and the images are contained in an image folder within the client React app. 

When I run the Rails backend locally, I have no trouble. But somehow by putting the backend on Heroku my frontend can no longer find its own images.

Comment: How do the images get there? Do you have some local build scripts or image pipelines that need to be run first on heroku?

Comment: When I run it locally, I'm just accessing them from the images folder. The string interpolation is taking a string from the backend that represents part of an image src url. That said, I'm very green with Heroku.

If there is something additional that needs to be run, and you think that's where my issue could be, do you think you could point me in the direction of some key words to start googling or a relevant article?

Thanks so much @Jkarttunen

Comment: What you need to look at is the build scripts for the front end. Are you running dev server locally (like 'yarn start' in CRA project), but compiling a production version when using the heroku server? What kind of build scripts for react do you use? Do you have a link to example project that uses the same build scripts?